# Reduce Multiple Recodes in one row from one table without use of agreegate function

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

```
SELECT * 
        FROM (
            SELECT id, No ,Date, ShiftType, Name, Dsc1, Dsc2 
        FROM xyz        
         ) T1
        PIVOT
        (
            min(ShiftType) for ShiftType IN ([Day],Evening,Night)
        ) AS T2
        ORDER BY No DESC
```

Got This Result from Above query

```
id | No  | Date       | Name | Desc1         | Desc2         | Day | Evening | Night
-------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 101 | 2018-01-05 | Nik  | Day Desc1     | Day Desc2     | Day - -
2  | 101 | 2018-01-05 | Nik  | Evening Desc1 | Evening Desc2 | - Evening -
3  | 101 | 2018-01-05 | Nik  | Night Desc1   | Night Desc  2 | - - Night
4  | 102 | 2018-01-19 | Mgh  | Night Desc1   | Night Desc2   | - - Night
```

OUTPUT Needed As Follows

```
id | No | Date       | Name | Desc1Day     | Desc2Day     | Desc1Evening         | Desc2Evening         | Desc1Night       | Desc2Night
-------------------------------------------------------------
1 | 101 | 2018-01-05 | Nik  | Day Desc1Day | Day Desc2Day | Evening Desc1Evening | Evening Desc2Evening | Night Desc1Night | Night Desc2Night
2 | 102 | 2018-01-19 | Mgh  | -            | -            | -                    | -                    | Night Desc1Night | Night Desc2Night
```

Comment: Do not use pivot two times, It can be done with `Group + Case` instead

Comment: please give example

Comment: ***Why*** do you want to reduce the rows without using aggregates?  That's what aggregates ARE...

Comment: yes right. how we can do that without aggregation?

Comment: ?!***WHY***!? do you want to do it without aggregation!?!?!?

Comment: i am concern with result whichever solution is suitable it is acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use aggregates. It makes ***zero*** sense to collapse multiple rows into a single row without them.

```
SELECT
  MIN(`id`),
  `No`,
  `Date`,
  `Name`,
  MAX(CASE WHEN `ShiftType` = 'Day'     THEN `dsc1` END)   AS Desc1Day,
  MAX(CASE WHEN `ShiftType` = 'Day'     THEN `dsc2` END)   AS Desc2Day,
  MAX(CASE WHEN `ShiftType` = 'Evening' THEN `dsc1` END)   AS Desc1Evening,
  MAX(CASE WHEN `ShiftType` = 'Evening' THEN `dsc2` END)   AS Desc2Evening,
  MAX(CASE WHEN `ShiftType` = 'Night'   THEN `dsc1` END)   AS Desc1Night,
  MAX(CASE WHEN `ShiftType` = 'Night'   THEN `dsc2` END)   AS Desc2Night
FROM
  xyz
GROUP BY
  `No`,
  `Date`,
  `Name`
```

Answer (score 0):

`Group + Case` in use:

```
select
    [No], [date], [Name]
    , max(iif(ShiftType = [Day], Dsc1, null)) [Day Desc1Day]
    , max(iif(ShiftType = [Day], Dsc2, null)) [Day Desc2Day]
    --list of columns you need
from
    xyz
group by [No], [date], [Name]
```

Comment: Thanks Uzi. Its Works for me... :) ;)